# What makes yum difficult with RAID

Tags: mysql, installation, disk-structures

I as working with someone on a redhat server using RAID 10 with MySQL, and they mentioned it is hard to use yum when having a raid setup.  Is this true? If so, what actually makes it 'difficult'?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @MarkSinkinson MySQL, we are using algorithms on the server that uses MySQL and python.

Comment: No problem, you'd just tagged it as SQL Server, so I was a little confused!

Comment: @MarkSinkinson Just realized that, thanks for fixing it

Comment: yum is a software package manager. It isn't aware of what RAID level you're using. I'd suggest asking the person who told you this for clarification, as it seems to make no sense. This is like saying 'it's difficult to use RAID5 with Windows Update'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about sys admin functions in general. It probably belongs on serverfault instead.

Comment: @DavidSpillet and James soryy i didnt know servervault is the more appropriate location.  If it is downvoted because of that it should be migrated.  If it is downvoted because the answer is, raid is irrelevant, im not sure i agree with the downvote since that is the answer

Comment: The vote to close isn't a downvote, it is a vote to close and suggest a better location for the question. "hard to use yum when having a RAID setup" definitely makes this more a SF question than a DBA one IMO even with the connected MySQL reference.

Comment: @David there was a downvote as well (and I've just added mine). Thanks for trying to help the OP, but I've opted not to migrate because I don't think they'd accept it due to low research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither MySQL nor Yum are explicitly aware of RAID *at all*. All mySQL cares about is that it has filesystems to put its files on, if that is hosted on a RAID volume (or NFS share, or anything else) or not makes no difference to it. The same for Yum - it is just a package manager and does not need to be aware of the intricacies of the block device the filesystems it uses are stored on.

The only thing I can think that they might mean is converting an already installed RedHat install to use a RAID volume for its primary filesystems (or only filesystem if it is all installed in a single filesystem), which can be a lot of faf to do in-place (you are better off, in terms of difficulty and safety, building a new machine with the RAID setup and migrating your databases over).